# Azure Backup Agent Issue

Tags: azure, backup

When I try to register the Azure Backup Agent from my Windows 7 machine, the following error appear:

> The Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent cannot connect to the OBEngine service. (ID: 100052)

Verify that the OBEngine service is present in the Services Control Panel and that the port 6049 is available.

I've checked that the service is running and the port is available. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error many times when my DPM online recovery points attempt to run.  I believe they fail because other backup jobs (like disk-to-disk jobs) are still running on the same protected data sources.  So the online recovery points start while another backup is already running and it fails.  This causes the `OBENGINE` service to falter and get *stuck*. I have had good luck with spreading out my backup job schedules within my protection groups. For instance, my disk-to-disk backups run in the latePM/earlyAM. My Online Recovery Points run during the work day, lateAM/earlyPM.

If I find some online backups failed with error:
**The Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent cannot connect to the OBEngine service. (ID: 100052)**
...I first look to see if any backups are running. If not, I restart the OBENGINE service.  When you look in services, this is the "Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent" which is running `obengine.exe`.  Here is a good command to restart this service, which you can run on your DPM server in a command prompt or in `PowerShell`:

```
net stop obengine && net stop obengine
```

After restarting the service, restart the online recovery point jobs that failed.  However it is likely your jobs may fail again tomorrow, so get those schedules spread out.

Comment: Other things to consider:
1) Your Azure Vault credentials and certificates are correct.
2) Your Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent (MARS Agent) is up to date on your DPM server.
3) Your DPM server is updated to one of the latest Update Rollups.

**I read where another users have disassembled everything and reassembled it, and had luck.  Such as removing protection in Protection Groups, Removing the vault within Azure, create a new vault, then re-protect the data sources with online backups enabled.